# What is a Nowerk Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Nowerk Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Nowerk Words™ | Not Nowerk Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| COG | PRONG |
| SNUG | TIGHT |
| MAELSTROM | WHIRLPOOL |
| COZY | COMFORTABLE |
| SPRY | AGILE |
| HUG | EMBRACE |
| LUG | HAUL |
| NUDGE | PROD |
| FLOUNDER | FLAIL |
| RIG | APPARATUS |

CSV Version:

```
Nowerk Words™,Not Nowerk Words™
COG,PRONG
SNUG,TIGHT
MAELSTROM,WHIRLPOOL
COZY,COMFORTABLE
SPRY,AGILE
HUG,EMBRACE
LUG,HAUL
NUDGE,PROD
FLOUNDER,FLAIL
RIG,APPARATUS
```

These are not the only examples of Nowerk Words™, a few more exist.

An Enigmatic Hint:

> Counter **Counter** Counter

The solution to the enigmatic hint:

> The hint above is supposed to mean **center counter**, a chess opening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Nowerk Word™ is

> a word of Scandinavian origin, as seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Scandinavian_origin

The hint was very helpful, in that

> another name for the Center Counter chess opening is the Scandinavian Defense. Maelstrom was the clear standout in the list, and a little googling came up with the Scandinavian link. Pretty interesting commonality, nice puzz!

Comment: Aah, NOrway-sWEden-denmaRK!

Comment: Ooh good call, super clever! Hadn't figured out the title.

Comment: Perfect! $\!\!$